# Animating just path/shape, without text in raphael.js set

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, shapes

I have a big problem animating shapes in raphael. First approach was to keep shape and text separately, but ten i faced problem, then i hover text, shape isn't animating (it should), then, i created set with shape and text in it. not i can access path from a object, but i can't animate it (i want to animate only shape, exluding text, but then i hover text, shape should be animating). how i can solve this problem?
Thank you!

```
    this[0].animate is not a function
```

[Break On This Error]

this[0].animate({ fill: attributes.fill }, 300);

```
    var st = r.set();
        st.push(obj);
        st.push(text);
        console.log(st);
        st.hover(function () {
            console.log(this.id);
            this[0].animate({ fill: '#204250' }, 300);
            this[0].g = this.glow({ color: "#0e2e3b", width: 12 });
        }, function () {
            this[0].animate({ fill: attributes.fill }, 300);
            this[0].g.remove();
        }).click(function (e) {
```

Comment: add a jsfiddel with more information? What about `$(this).animate(...)`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `this[0]` within a raphael set it will actually refer to the DOM element, which doesn't have an animate method because it's not a raphael object.

I presume this is a workaround because applying `.hover` to a Raphael set it will actually iterate through the elements of the set and apply the same event to all the elements within the set.

There are a couple of ways to work around this, if your code is as simple as you have posted this might suffice:

```
var st = r.set();
        st.push(obj);
        st.push(text);
        console.log(st);
        st.hover(function () {
            var element = (this.type === "text") ? this.prev : this
            element.animate({ fill: '#204250' }, 300);
            element.g = element.glow({ color: "#0e2e3b", width: 12 });
        }, function () {
            var element = (this.type === "text") ? this.prev : this
            element.animate({ fill: attributes.fill }, 300);
            element.g.remove();
        });​
```